# How to find My Wifi has internet or Not Ionic 2?

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I have created an application in ionic 2 where I check the Network availability. My app does not show when network is established. I want to check if connection has internet or not? How do we check the connected network has internet connection or not using Ionic 2?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(private toast: ToastController, private network: Network, public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }

  ionViewDidEnter() {

    this.network.onConnect().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
      this.displayNetworkUpdate(data.type);
    }, error => console.error(error));

    this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
      this.displayNetworkUpdate(data.type);
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }

  displayNetworkUpdate(connectionState: string){
    let networkType = this.network.type
    this.toast.create({
      message: `You are now ${connectionState} via ${networkType}`,
      duration: 3000
    }).present();
  }


}
```

Comment: This is very broad if you haven't tried anything yet. What code have you tried or what research have you done?

Comment: I have specified the code I have done in my application. I get online when I am connected via any network. But How to ensure that the network has internet connectivity?

Comment: Don't you have any sort of back-end that you can attempt to connect to and, if you can't, just declare the app offline?

Comment: You are right. But when application opens up I want to declare that there is no internet connection on the device.

Comment: So, if you have a backend, create an endpoint, call it in `app.component` page-load, if you don't get any response/error --> No internet connection, else --> internet connection